# Jest encountered an unexpected token with React App

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

When trying to run tests with Jest in a React app, I get a 'Jest encountered an unexpected token' error.

I bootstrapped the app with `npx create-react-app`.
A simple demo-test where I check if 1 + 1 = 2 works. 
But as soon as I want to test components I get the above error.

I tried to configure babel with `babel.config.js` and added jest configuration in my package.json but still the error remains.

Here's my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-icons": "~3.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "~3.1.1",
    "react-validation-framework": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/assetTransformer.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/assetTransformer.js"
    }
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.0.1",
    "enzyme": "~3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "~1.14.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.9.0",
    "sinon": "^7.4.2"
  }
```

I have a `setupTests.js` file in src/**tests** written as follow:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

The component I am testing is in src/App and is as follow

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import UserForm from './components/UserForm'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserForm/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The `App.test.js` is in src/**tests** and looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import App from '../App';

describe('First React component test with Enzyme', () => {
   it('renders without crashing', () => {
      shallow(<App />);
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried the solutions offered within the create-react-app issue? https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6933

Comment: create-react-app installs and configures Jest for you so unless you ejected (not recommended) you’ll want to remove jest as a dev dependency and revert your npm test command to what it was originally

Comment: Yes I tried this one

Comment: move your `setupTests.js` from `src/test/` to `src/` directory. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests#src-setuptestsjs

Comment: Hey Talgat that was it thanks!